# what is difference between datalines and cards statement

Tags: sas

I am seeking job on SAS tool. interviewer asked me this question I said no difference, both are used to read internal data but he told there is a difference between cards and datalines statement .

kindly help me to crack this question.

Comment: Either you miss heard the question or the interviewer doesn't know how SAS works.  The only difference between a `CARDS;` statement and a `DATALINES;` statement is the age of the programmer.

Comment: Cards were older datalines, that is the only difference last i know

Answer (score 5):

There is no significant difference between the two.  `CARDS` is [defined as an alias of `DATALINES`](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lestmtsref/69738/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p0114gachtut3nn1and4ap8ke9nf.htm), and by definition an alias should have identical behavior to the statement it is an alias of.

There is an  insignificant difference, which is really simply an undefined behavior; it is explained on page 4 of [Andrew Kuligowski's 2007 paper](http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/forum2007/220-2007.pdf), and related to how `cards` and `datalines` have slightly different results when used in a `file` statement (which they are not intended to be used with).  The behavior is slightly different now for `datalines` in modern SAS (9.4); it gives an error, but a different one from `cards`.  However, it is simply undefined behavior; it would be an absurd thing for an interviewer to expect as an answer.

Your interviewer may have been referring to `datalines` versus [`datalines4`](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lestmtsref/69738/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p1mm9b070wj962n16q0v1d9uku5q.htm), or `cards` versus `cards4`; those *are* different,  because the latter requires four `;` to end instead of one (to allow for the possibility of a semicolon in the data itself).

Comment: You can get more information from, for example, [this thread](https://communities.sas.com/t5/Base-SAS-Programming/Datalines-VS-Cards/td-p/96306) and various other similar discussions on the internet.